# Does date fall within 7 days? PHP

Tags: php, date

Is there a way to find out if a date falls within 7 days of the current date using PHP? If there is, would it also be possible to figure out how many days away that date is?

Comment: In case you are not dealing with timezones yet, I suggest you have it. Once you start using different timezones for your application , you will get into trouble with date manipulations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$date = strtotime('2010-11-28');

if (strtotime('-7 days') < $date && $date < strtotime('+7 days')) {
    // yup
}

$difference = abs($date - time()) / 60 / 60 / 24;
```

Could be refined a bit if you care about edge cases, whole days and daylight-savings/leap seconds issues, but this should hopefully give you the right idea. Of course the [`Date` class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) should be the preferred method to handle this, but it's only available in PHP 5.3+.

Answer (score 1):

For the first one, add 7 days to the current date and see which is greater.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

For the second one:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php

Comment: But the first link is for MySQL not PHP?